# File download fails after SpringBoot Update (from 2.5 to 3.2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

After migrating from SpringBoot 2.5 to 3.2 a generated PDF (using itext7-core:7.2.2) becomes invalid after downloading it.

There are no issues viewing it in browser but when I download the pdf its coming without any extension and even if I download the file and give the extension manually the content is the web page and not the PDF. I saw this by opening the downloaded file using Notepad (contains **source code of the web page**.. not even the page from where I am generating the pdf.)

The main changes I made for the migration(SB2.5>sb3.2) in the class where pdf creation code exists is replacing javax to jakarta, mainly `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` to `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse`

I don't think there is any issue with the pdf generation code(how i am using itext library) because it is working in SB2.5.

Roughly below is my pdf generation code,

```
public void pdfgeneration(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
           throws IOException, ServletException {
try {
           ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(ba);
           PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
           Document document = new Document(pdfDocument, PageSize.A4, false);

           PdfDocumentInfo pdfMetaData = pdfDocument.getDocumentInfo();
           pdfMetaData.setTitle(Constants.TITLE);
           pdfMetaData.setAuthor(Constants.AUTHOR);
           pdfMetaData.setSubject(Constants.SUBJECT);
           pdfMetaData.setProducer("");
      .
      .
      .
       document.close();
       response.setHeader("Expires","0");
       response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate,post-check=0,pre-check=0");
       response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
       response.setContentType("application/pdf");
       response.setContentLength(ba.size());
       OutputStream outy = response.getOutputStream();
       ba.writeTo(outy);
       outy.flush();
       outy.close();
}catch(){
....
}
```

If anyone has worked on this/ faced this issue and remediated please let me know.

Comment: *"even if i download the file and give the extention manually and open using Adobe reader it gives an error "* - have you checked the actual content of that file?

Comment: I just checked it, I just opened that file with notepad, and to my surprise it is the source code of the home page.. not even the page from where I am generating the pdf. I am very confused at this point.

Comment: That's really confusing. Apparently your issues are not iText related. Either you use SB incorrectly or you have found a bug in it.

Comment: Can you please explain exactly what you are suspecting as using SB incorrectly ? Mainly i am suspecting the new HttpServletResponse object and i also have spring security implemented ... not sure if anything is getting blocked there.

Comment: *"Can you please explain exactly what you are suspecting as using SB incorrectly ?"* - Nothing specific. If the issue had been iText related, I might have been able to help, but not with a SB issue.

Comment: "I just checked it, I just opened that file with notepad, and to my surprise it is the source code of the home page" => This is not an iText related question - voting to close this here... => Or you rephrase it to something spring security related...

Comment: @Lonzak i have changed.

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be, that you downloaded an entirely different file, not your expected PDF document.

With Spring Boot (form 2.5 to) 3.2, the dependency spring-security, got much restricter. [Now, by default, spring-security denies all](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/authorization.html#_ensure_all_messages_have_defined_authorization_rules) requests that have not been authorized. Please read [the migration guide carefully](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/index.html), as quite a lot has changed.

I guess, you downloaded either the error, login or index page.